# hide bootstrap dropdown menu on item is clicked

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following dropdown menu

```
<li class="dropdown menustatus open" id="user-status">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">
    <div class="online-status" style="display: none;"></div>
    <div class="busy-status" style=""></div>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user" style="margin-top: 10px;">
    <li class="status">
      <a href="http://localhost:3000/status/online" data-remote="true" id="online-status" style="color:#4b3087;"><i class="fa fa-circle online"></i> Online</a>
    </li>
    <li class="status">
      <a href="http://localhost:3000/status/busy" data-remote="true" id="busy-status" style="color:#4b3087;"><i class="fa fa-circle busy"></i> Busy</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

I'm trying to remove the "open" class when the user click on #online-status or #busy-status like this:

```
$("#online-status").click(function (){
    $(".busy-status").hide();
    $(".online-status").show();
    $("li.open").removeClass("open");
  });


  $("#busy-status").click(function (){
    $(".online-status").hide();
    $(".busy-status").show();
    $("li.open").removeClass("open");
  });
```

I also tried this way:

```
$("#busy-status").click(function (){
  $( "li.dropdown.menustatus" ).find( "open" ).removeClass("open");
});

$("#online-status").click(function (){
  $( "li.dropdown.menustatus" ).find( "open" ).removeClass("open");
});
```

But I can't hide the dropdown.

Any idea or suggestion please.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

## [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/6mSBa6tS98)

```
 $("#online-status").click(function () {
            $("#user-status").removeClass("open");
        });


        $("#busy-status").click(function () {
            $("#user-status").removeClass("open");
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

put `preventDefault()` to stop Default Behaviour:

```
$("#online-status").click(function (e){
     e.preventDefault();
    $(".busy-status").hide();
    $(".online-status").show();
    $("li.open").removeClass("open");
  });


  $("#busy-status").click(function (e){
      e.preventDefault();
    $(".online-status").hide();
    $(".busy-status").show();
    $("li.open").removeClass("open");
  });
```

[**WORKING FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/sw5q9hc0/4/)